# Cloud Print and thermal printers

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, google-cloud-print

I am using Google Cloud Print for print generated PDF documents in a web app.

All was working fine in all printer types that i use (HP, Zebra, etc) but about 2 weeks ago all Zebra printers (thermal printers) are printing PDF documents in portrait mode (Ignoring printer settings).

What i need?: That Google Clout print keeps my printers settings.

My tests:
I changed printer settings (Document orientation: Portrait/Landscape).
I rotated the PDF documents before send to Google Cloud Print.
I sent ticket printer/capabilities but Google Cloud Print ignored it.

I'm sure that it's a Google Update.

Exist other people that are using Google Cloud Print with thermal printers?

There is any solution for it?

UPDATE1:

Google updated some documentation https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/?hl=es-419&csw=1

This does not solve my problem, but I posted a library in java that I hope will be useful to others and maybe someone will be encouraged to participate.

This library is compatible with version 1 and 2 of the Google Cloud Print API

Github repository https://github.com/fsistemas/GoogleCloudPrintApiClientJava

Comment: Can you update that link to the documentation? We are experiencing the same thing with our web app, we send labels and receipts and such to printers and we keep getting reports that they randomly rotate.

Comment: Hello @TroyAnderson, We stopped using Google Cloud Print and returned to http://www.qoppa.com

Comment: @FranciscoPérez, We want are in similar use-case. We can to access thermal printer from a web page which is contained inside android application in android tablet.
When I try to register with thermal printer in Google Cloud Print in android tablet, it didn't detect the printer.
How did you configured thermal printer in google cloud print?

Comment: @KulinChoksi did you ever figure this out, I came across the same problem, the thermal printer is connected with Bluetooth, however to add that as a google cloud printer , its not detecting

Comment: @Venkat, haven't checked for that later. sorry, no idea.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to try [PrintNode](http://www.printnode.com) which has support for all major thermal printers.  It can print both .pdf's files, zpl and epl printer languages.  You install the PrintNode client on a desktop machine and can send printjobs via their JSON API or web interface.  It's alot faster than Google Cloud Print.